# java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date while trying to insert data to database table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

String query1 ="insert into ORDER_T(ORDER_ID,ordernumber,ordertotal,ORDERDESCRIPTION,CREATEDDATE,"
                + "UPDATEDDATE) values(?,?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'dd/mm/yyyy'),TO_DATE(?,'dd/mm/yyyy'))";

```
        preparedSt=con.prepareStatement(query1);
        preparedSt.setString(1, order.getOrderId());
        preparedSt.setString(2, order.getOrderNumber());
        preparedSt.setString(3, order.getOrderDescription());
        preparedSt.setBigDecimal(4, order.getOrderTotal());         
        preparedSt.setDate(5,(java.sql.Date) order.getCreatedDate());// java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
        preparedSt.setDate(6, (java.sql.Date) order.getUpdatedDate());// java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
        result=preparedSt.executeUpdate();
```

**console**
connection success!!
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at com.cloudbill.order.process.OrderProcessorImpl.placeOrder(OrderProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at com.cloudbill.order.bo.OrderMain.main(OrderMain.java:174)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at com.cloudbill.order.process.OrderProcessorImpl.placeOrder(OrderProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at com.cloudbill.order.bo.OrderMain.main(OrderMain.java:174)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
    java.sql.Date sqlCreatedDate = new java.sql.Date(order.getCreatedDate().getTime());
        java.sql.Date sqlUpdatedDateDate = new java.sql.Date(order.getUpdatedDate().getTime());
        prepairedSt.setDate(5,sqlCreatedDate);// 
        prepairedSt.setDate(6, sqlUpdatedDateDate);//
```

Comment: Thanks thomas..ur code is working fine..now the problem is solved.